# Setup google Ecommerce Tracking with Paypal using .Net

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I need to have GA  e-commerce tracking system setup for my website with .net.
my transactions are from paypal.

if anyone has experience with this before if you can guide or have simple code examples that would be great!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-########-#']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.mydomain.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);


    _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
      '117',           // order ID - required
      'StoreName.com',  // affiliation or store name
      '35.96',          // total - required
      '0',           // tax
      '0',              // shipping
      '',       // city
      '',     // state or province
      ''             // country
    ]);
    _gaq.push(['_addItem',
      '117',           // order ID - required
      '1',           // SKU/code - required
      '1 Pack',        // product name
      'Catagory5',          // catagory   
      '35.96,          // unit price - required
      '1'               // quantity - required
    ]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to take the Javascript snippet that Google Analytics gives you to place on your thank you / receipt page and then dynamically populate it using your shopping cart data or whatever you're using.

If you want to make sure this is accurately tracked, though, you'll want to make sure to use PayPal's Express Checkout API as opposed to standard HTML buttons because without the API there is no guarantee that the user will actually make it back to your final page, so in those cases it wouldn't get tracked.  With Express Checkout that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply....do I need to add the code where I have added on the top or the shorter version of the code snippet?

Comment: It's an extra snippet separate from the basic analytics snippet.  Here's a guide:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

Comment: how about the Paypal transfer? do i need to include it in my code behind? or its not needed?

Comment: You mean the transfer from PayPal to your bank?  You wouldn't want to track that in Analytics eCommerce tracking as that's not an actual sale.

Comment: sorry the Paypal data transfer it's like a auto generated code by paylap

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Your PayPal button code wouldn't need to change at all.  You just need to make sure you can dynamically populate the eCommerce tracking code.